# How can $x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-x_n}$ be a decreasing sequence on [0, 1)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

For $x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-x_n}$ on $[0, 1)$, we have that $(1-x_{n+1})^2=1-x_n$, where LHS and RHS are both less than $1$, which implies that the sequence is increasing. But the textbook asks to prove that it's decreasing. What's my error?

Comment: Why would both sides being less than one in that inequality imply the sequence is increasing?

Comment: @Joanpemo: because for any $x\in [0, 1)$, $x^2 < x$.

Comment: Thank you, yet those two sides are of different elements: it is not the same $\;x_n\;$ on the left and on the right.

Comment: We can also expand and get $2x_{n+1}-x_{n+1}^2=x_n \implies x_{n+1}(1-x_{n+1})=x_n \implies x_{n+1} \ge x_n$ (since $0 < 1-x_{n+1} \le 1$). Indeed, the textbook must be mistaken.

Comment: Look at my edited answer, which I edited thanks to the comment by Marty. This changes everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, let $x_n=\frac{9}{25}$. Then $x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-9/25}=1/5\lt x_n$. In general,
$$x_{n+1}=(1-\sqrt{1-x_n})\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x_n}}{1+\sqrt{1-x_n}}=  \frac{x_n}{1+\sqrt{1-x_n}}\lt x_n.$$
The sequence is indeed decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the sequence in non-negative (as you proved or were given. It appears in the question)

$$x_{n+1}\ge x_n\iff 1-\sqrt{1-x_n}\ge x_n\iff 1-2x_n+x^2_n\ge1-x_n\iff$$

$$\iff x_n^2-x_n\ge0\iff x_n(x_n-1)\le0$$

and the last inequality is trivial now...and I also get the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: Where's your $1+2x_n+x^2_n$ coming from?

Comment: @sequence From the squared binomial: $$1-\sqrt{1-x_n}\ge x_n\iff (1+x_n)^2\ge\left(\sqrt{1-x_n}\right)^2\iff 1+2x_n+x_n^2\ge 1-x_n$$

Comment: No. It is $1-x_n$ on the left/

Comment: @martycohen Thank you very much, you are right! Editing. Great catch, this changes everything, I believe.

Comment: If $x_n^2 - x_n\ge 0$ and $x_n^2 - x_n = x_n(x_n-1)$, then how is $x_n(x_n-1)\le 0$?

Comment: @sequence Because $\;x_n>0\;$,  yet $\;x_n-1<0\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler approach :

Consider the auxiliary sequence $v_n=1-u_n$ with $v_n\in [0,1]$, that verifies $v_{n+1}=\sqrt{v_n}$ : it is increasing to $1$; thus $u_n$ is  decreasing to $0$.

(many thanks to @Lutzl for correcting me)

Comment: No, $v_{n+1}=\sqrt{v_n}$ converges to $1$ for all $v_0>0$. Thus $u_n=1-v_n$ will converge to $0$.

Comment: @Lutzl You are evidently right. beginners' mistake... I correct it.

Answer (score 1):

One may write, for $n\geq1$,

> $$
> \begin{align}
> x_n-x_{n+1}&=\left(1-\sqrt{1-x_{n-1}}\right)-\left(1-\sqrt{1-x_n}\right)\\\\
> &=\sqrt{1-x_n}-\sqrt{1-x_{n-1}}\\\\
> &=\frac{x_{n-1}-x_n}{\sqrt{1-x_n}+\sqrt{1-x_{n-1}}}\\\\
> &=\cdots\\\\
> &=\frac{x_0-x_1}{\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt{1-x_k}+\sqrt{1-x_{k-1}}\right)}\:\color{blue}{\geq0}
> \end{align}
> $$

since $x_0-x_1=\sqrt{1-x_0}\:(1-\sqrt{1-x_0})$.

Comment: So if $x_0 > x_1$ the sequence is decreasing, and if $x_0 < x_1$ the sequence is increasing.

Comment: @martycohen Seeing the last equality I wrote above, using $x_0\in[0,1)$, then $x_0\geq x_1$. The sequence is decreasing.